# How to run system command asynchronously but still check if they are excecuted

Tags: r, asynchronous

I would like to run a lot of system commands asynchronously in the first part of my code, but then wait for them to finish in the second part of my code.

Right now I do that in the following way

```
for(command in commands){
system(command, wait = FALSE, intern = FALSE)
}
Sys.wait(300)
#run second part of my code using the files generated by the commands above
```

In other words. Right now I just run the commands asynchronously and guess that they will be completed in 300 seconds. Is there a way to explicitly check of the commands are all executed before continuing and at the same time run them asynchronously?

Comment: If you are using the files generated from the first part, can you check the modified time of those files?

Comment: I'm downloading an unknown number of files, so I could check if there have not been created any new files for a while, but it is kind of hacky.